# Destroying a prefab from mouse click raycast

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I want to destroy or remove a spawning prefab from my scene when the mouse clicks on the gameobject. I'm trying to use the code below from the Unity docs, however I'm presented with the following error:
`object reference not set to the instance of an object`.

This script is attached to my main camera. `onclick` crashes the game. Can anyone see where this is going wrong?

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class onClickDestroy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject destroyCube;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit(); //*
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) //**
            {
                print("true" + hit.point);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: in which line do you get the Exception?

Comment: `Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Make sure your `Camera` is really tagged as `MainCamera`

[image]

if not click there and select `MainCamera` from the list

[image]

**Solution 2**

Get and check the main camera at game start

```c#
priavte Camera _camera;

privtae void Awake()
{
    _camera = Camera.main;

    if(!_camera)
    {
        Debug.LogError("No Camera tagged MainCamera in Scene!");
        enabled = false;
    }
}
```

**Solution 3**

Or instead of using `Camera.main` at all instead get the `Camera` component directly

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class onClickDestroy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject destroyCube;

    privtae Camera _camera;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Ray ray = _camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                print("true" + hit.point);
            }
        }
    }
}
```